# How to performance test JavaScript in a web page on iPhone?

Tags: javascript, iphone, performance

Ive made a web page with quite extensive JavaScript. Its runs fine in my browser and in my iPhone simulator. However on my iPhone 3G its very sluggish. My iPhone is pretty buggy though and often freezes for no reason so I dont know if its just my device or too much / bad code.

Other than using lots of devices (might be difficult to get my hands on), is there a good way to test this? Thanks

Comment: It sounds like some application on your phone probably has a memory leak, which is causing your phone to slow down and/or freeze. What version of iOS is running on your iPhone?

Comment: iOS 5 and its an iPhone 3G. I think its just a buggy phone. When it goes wrong it freezes for a while but normally recovers when I lock it and unlock it again. This happens seemly randomly, when im browsing, emailing, in my phones settings, etc.

Comment: I'm amazed that iOS 5 runs on an iPhone 3G at all.